# typo3scan: path typo3/cms-scanner/config/Matcher/v8 does not exist

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I have a composer based TYPO3 8.7 installation with a dev requirement for `typo3/cms-scanner:dev-master` and `michielroos/typo3scan:dev-master`.

When I run e.g. `php vendor/bin/typo3scan scan --target 8 web/typo3conf/ext/be_secure_pw` I end up with this error message:

```
In MatcherBundle.php line 35:

  Path "/foo/bar/baz/vendor/michielroos/typo3scan/src/TYPO3Scan/Service/../../../../../typo3/cms-scanner/config/Matcher/v8" does not exist
```

The directory `vendor/typo3/cms-scanner/config/Matcher` is present, but there are no subdirectories for specific TYPO3 versions, e.g. `v8`.

Any ideas what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The composer package `michielroos/typo3scan` relies on a fork of `typo3/cms-scanner` and I had the original package by Oliver Hader included in my composer.json.

After switching to the fork now everything works fine!